# Crystal Report Viewer bboj is undefine error after windows update in IIS Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

My Asp.Net application developed with VS 2012 was working fine but when I updated my windows server 2012 r2 yesterday. The crystal report stop working after that update and showing blank. I tried everything, reinstall IIS by using windows feature, place fresh copy of my application, changed permission setting, place aspnet_client folder in www and in application folder. Still out of luck. 
I am sure that the problem appears after I install updates in my server. My office work suffers a lot due to this problem. An immediate help will be extremly appreciated.

Comment: Any one who want to answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem held aftermy system automatically updated .Net Framework to version 4.6.01055 which was not compatible with Crystal Report older version. I installed CRforVS_13_0_18.exe and restart the machine. It start working.